# How can I return each value from my for-each loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, contentful-api

I'm using Bootstrap vue table with contentful's API and could use some help with my code. I'm attempting to use a for loop to iterate over an array and get the property values. The console.info(episodes); call prints out each iteration for the var episodes, but now how do I bind this to my variable episodes. Using return only returns one result even outside of the for each loop. Any help or suggestions on another implementation is greatly appreciated. Full Template below.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Bootstrap Table</h1>
    <b-table striped responsive hover :items="episodes" :fields="fields"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
</style>
<script>
import axios from "axios";
// Config
import config from "config";
// Vuex
import store from "store";
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
// Services
import { formatEntry } from "services/contentful";
// Models
import { entryTypes } from "models/contentful";
// UI
import UiEntry from "ui/Entry";
import UiLatestEntries from "ui/LatestEntries";
const contentful = require("contentful");
const client = contentful.createClient({
  space: "xxxx",
  environment: "staging", // defaults to 'master' if not set
  accessToken: "xxxx"
});
export default {
  name: "contentful-table",
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [
        {
          key: "category",
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          key: "episode_name",
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          key: "episode_acronym",
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          key: "version",
          sortable: true
        }
      ],
      episodes: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    return Promise.all([
      // fetch the owner of the blog
      client.getEntries({
        content_type: "entryWebinar",
        select: "fields.title,fields.description,fields.body,fields.splash"
      })
    ])
      .then(response => {
        // console.info(response[0].items);
        return response[0].items;
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.episodes = function() {
          var arrayLength = response.length;
          var episodes = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            // console.info(response[i].fields.title + response[i].fields.splash + response[i].fields.description + response[i].fields.body );
            var episodes = [
              {
                category: response[i].fields.title,
                episode_name: response[i].fields.splash,
                episode_acronym: response[i].fields.description,
                version: response[i].fields.body
              }
            ];
            // episodes.forEach(category => episodes.push(category));
            console.info(episodes);
          }
          return episodes;
        };
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on the response array to return all the elements.

In your current example you keep re-setting the `episodes` variable, instead of the `push()` you actually want to do. The `map` method is still a more elegant way to solve your problem.

```js
this.episodes = response.map((item) => {
    return {
        category: item.fields.title,
        episode_name: items.fields.splash,
        episode_acronym: item.fields.description,
        version: item.fields.body
    }
})
```

You can update the `last` then to match the `last` then below

```js
]).then(response => {
    return response[0].items;
})
.then((response) => {
    this.episodes = response.map((item) => {
        return {
            category: item.fields.title,
            episode_name: items.fields.splash,
            episode_acronym: item.fields.description,
            version: item.fields.body
        };
    });
})
.catch(console.error)
```

You do have an unnecessary second `then`, but I left it there so that you could see what I am replacing.

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you explain what item corresponds to in the response.map((item) line?

Comment: @Shawn It is an individual item of the `response` array. You can also check the link to the documentation regarding the `map` method.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how this would work in my original script, I'm confused on whether I need to remove the below section of my code

   .then(response => {
        // console.info(response[0].items);
        return response[0].items
      })

Comment: @Shawn Added more code that you could drop into your project.

Comment: I was getting an error that items is not defined, it was due to a typo in your response, the episode_name property. I think I'm on the right track now, Thank you so much for this.

Comment: @Shawn I used the same property values you were returning in the modified object.